# Escaping quotes coming from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I get some data from JSON and put it as a custom attribut `data-info` into an `a-tag`. When clicking on this link, the information should appear:

```
$("#div").append("<a href='#' data-info='" + value.info + "'>" + value.name "</a>");
```

Unfortunately, JSON may contain some quotes that break my code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="trends" data-wiki="Some "infos" with 'quotes'">Some text</a>
```

How can I escape all quotes coming from JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can use `attr`

```
var $link = $('<a href="#" />').text(value.name).attr('data-info', value.info);
$("#div").append($link);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it properly.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute("href","#");
a.setAttribute("data-info",value.info);
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value.name));
$("#div").append(a);
```

Done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you wanted:

```
$("#div").append("<a href='#' data-info='" + value.info.replace("'", "\'") + "'>" + value.name "</a>");
```

But you should do it like @Niet the Dark Absol's answer